# External Flash Loader gets "failed to download Segment[0]" error on STM32CubeIDE

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I have made a custom external flash loader(.stldr) file for my STM32 based board and this file works great with ST Link Utility(Read, Write and Erase) are work fine and i can Program the board correctly. But when i try to use the created .stldr file by STM32CubeIDE the erasing process well done but when the downloading process gets start then **"failed to download Segment[0]"** error pups up.

Could any one help me with the problem?

```html
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 6.0.0
Copyright (c) 2021, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
        InitWhile                  : Enabled

Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
Debugger connected
Waiting for debugger connection...
      -------------------------------------------------------------------
                       STM32CubeProgrammer v2.9.0-RC01                  
      -------------------------------------------------------------------

ST-LINK SN  : 48FF6D068366565223471581
ST-LINK FW  : V2J39S7
Board       : --
Voltage     : 3.24V
SWD freq    : 4000 KHz
Connect mode: Under Reset
Reset mode  : Hardware reset
Device ID   : 0x450
Revision ID : Rev V
Device name : STM32H7xx
Flash size  : 2 MBytes
Device type : MCU
Device CPU  : Cortex-M7
BL Version  : 0x90



Memory Programming ...
Opening and parsing file: ST-LINK_GDB_server_a23188.srec
  File          : ST-LINK_GDB_server_a23188.srec
  Size          : 389352 Bytes
  Address       : 0x08000000 


Erasing memory corresponding to segment 0:
Erasing internal memory sector 0
Erasing memory corresponding to segment 1:
Erasing external memory sectors [0 3]
Download in Progress:


Error: failed to download Segment[0]
Error: failed to download the File
Shutting down...
Exit.
```

MCU = STM32H743iit6

QSPI Flash = W25Q256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was for the version of STM32CubeIDE 1.8

I downgraded to the STM32CubeIDE1.7 and the problem is solved.

**Edited:**
I found the problem. According to these pictures(First for STM32CubeIDE 1.8 and Second for STM32CubeIDE 1.7)

[image]
[image]

- The STM32CubeIDE 1.8 uses the STM32CubeProgrammer 2.9 and this makes the problems but the STM32CubeIDE 1.7 uses STM32CubeProgrammer 2.8 and it makes every things work fine.

**Solution2:**

Alternative to downgrading stm32CubeIDE from 1.8 to 1.7 version, you can only copy and replace the below directory contents of the STM32CubeIDE 1.7:

```
C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.7.0\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.win32_2.0.0.202105311346\tools\bin
```

to the directory :

```
C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.8.0\STM32CubeIDE\plugins\com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.cubeprogrammer.win32_2.0.100.202110141430\tools\bin
```

of the STM32CubeIDE 1.8 and every things will work well.